# How to know the features and their contributions of a specific sample in RandomForest

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn

How can I find the features and their contributions that impacted the prediction of a specific sample, say row 5

### Update

thanks to @FatihAkici

I can apply the TreeInterpreter now

```
from treeinterpreter import treeinterpreter as ti

instances = X_train.loc[[1,2]]
print(rf.predict(instances))
prediction, biases, contributions = ti.predict(rf, instances)

for i in range(len(instances)):
    print ("Instance", i)
    print ("Bias (trainset mean)", biases[i])
    print ("Feature contributions:")
    for c, feature in sorted(zip(contributions[i], 
                                 rf.feature_importances_), 
                             key=lambda x: ~abs(x[0].any())):
        print (feature, np.round(c, 2))
    print ("-"*20 )

print (prediction)
print (biases + np.sum(contributions, axis=1))
```

My question is why is there  `[ 0.12 -0.12]` two values that seem to be positive and negative, rather than one value of that feature. Here is my output

Comment: First, `feature_importances_` is an attribute of RandomForestClassifier, not of the predicted data. So will not work with `y_pred`. Second, it doesnt make sense to get the feature importance of test data. The model can only find the importance of features in the data it has seen (its trained on). Third, whats the second question?

Comment: @Vivek Kumar, your second point there is my question ( I will modify the question to reflect your thoughts), can I then train the whole dataset and then extract the feature importance of that specific point.
I am formulating my second question

Comment: So are you saying you want to know the features which impacted the classification of a specific sample?

Comment: Those will be those features which were deemed important during the training period. For prediction (testing), the determined coeffs are just processed and applied to the testing data. No new information is determined.

Comment: @VivekKumar, let me re-phrase this a bit. For the randomForestClassifier to determine a sample, it asks a trail of questions with weights. For a specific sample, what are those trails and weights that led it to predict that sample correctly

Comment: @Victor There is not one one path per sample but `n_estimators` different paths - one for each decision tree. As far I know, no weights are involved. You could try to count how often each feature was used in a split along the path, if that is what you want. (I'm not sure this can be considered an *importance measure*.) Sklearn does not expose such functionality so you would have to implement the `decision_path` function yourself.

Comment: @kazemakase thank you for your edition, I will try digging into the decision_path for randomForest, the question has also been updated

Comment: You can also have a look at [lime](https://github.com/marcotcr/lime)

Comment: @Dan can you kindly help at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48891323/using-lime-for-interpreting-decision-tree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can know the features and their contributions (weight is not the right term) that impacted the prediction of a specific observation. This actually constitutes the decision_path for how it made that decision of that particular observation. What you are looking for is [TreeInterpreter](https://github.com/andosa/treeinterpreter).

**The second question is:** Why are there always two values for each variable and instance (such as `[0.12 -0.12]` for the first feature and first instance) that seem to be positive and negative, rather than one value of that feature?

**So my answer is:** Each of these lists (such as `[0.12 -0.12]`) just represents the contribution of a feature to the final probability of an instance being in class 1 and class 2. Remember, features never dictate what class an instance must be in, but instead, they increase or decrease the final class probabilities of an instance. So 0.12 means that Feature 1 added 0.12 to the probability of instance 0 being in class 1, and reduced its probability of being in class 2 by 0.12. These values are always symmetric, meaning that whatever makes an instance more likely to be in class 1 makes it less likely to be in class 2.

Similarly, Feature 2 reduced probability of instance 1 being class 1 by 0.05, and increased its probability of being class 2 by 0.05.

So each feature contributed (added or reduced) to instance 1 being in class 1 by: 0.12, -0.05, 0.22, 0.14, 0.07, 0.01. Now add these all up to the bias of being in class 1 (0.49854), you get 1, which is the final probability of that instance being in class 1, as shown by the model output.

Similarly, add all of the second values of each list, and add the bias of being in class 2 (0.50146), you get 0, which is the final probability of that instance being in class 2, as shown by the model output above.

Finally repeat the exact same exercise for instance 1, i.e. add -0.03, -0.11, 0.06, 0, -0.06, -0.04 to the bias of 0.49854, you get 0.32, which is the `P{instance1 = class1}`. And add 0.03, 0.11, -0.06, 0, 0.06, 0.04 to the bias of 0.50146, you get 0.68, which is the `P{instance1 = class2}`. Therefore these numbers constitute a full trajectory of contributions, from the initial bias to the final classification probability of an instance.

I had answered a very similar question at a conceptual level on datascience.stackexchange.com, please feel free to check it out [by clicking here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/25482/understanding-what-is-going-on/25528#25528).

Comment: Akici I have edited the code to print the feature names instead of the title, do yo have any idea why does it print 2 values instead of one ?

Comment: @Victor You've perfectly figured it out, congrats! Regarding the 2 values, that is pretty typical. I encountered that during my modeling in both Python and R, and it just represents the two categories of the dependent variable (Y). Each feature of the model increases or decreases the final result (class probability) of the classification model. First value is the feature contribution to class 1, and second for class 2. They are always symmetric, meaning that whatever makes an observation more likely to be in class 1 makes it less likely to be in class 2.

Comment: thank you for your kind words. I would like to further understand those two values. If I am predicting why did a certain sample produce that certain class, shouldn’t I get one definite value for each feature rather than two ? Because otherwise, a treeintrepreter is not giving me the certain features for that certain sample but rather a generalization. What do you think about that ?

Comment: @Victor Sorry about the late edit; I added my explanation on how those two symmetric values in the output work. Please let me know if anything is unclear, and we'll discuss further.

Comment: @Victor Just added a sentence: "features never dictate what class an instance must be in, but instead, they increase or decrease the final class probabilities of an instance." This should clarify your confusion I guess. Each feature just bumps up or pulls down **slightly** the class probabilities.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed and in-depth explanation. After reading so many websites and the original article, I understood best from your explanation.

Comment: @FaithAkici, for discussion purposes, do you think we can expose the decision_path now that we know the probability of each feature contribution. Such as feature 1, feature 5, feature 3. where this order presents the decision path of the algorithm ?

Comment: I have started this for decision_path, I hope you can contribute

Comment: That's absolutely possible, @Victor! You should just have an empty Class1Path list, collect the first elements of each of those lists inside the `for c, feature in sorted(...)` loop, and append them to Class1Path. And do the same for the second elements, and append to Class2Path. I can help with the code as well, probably this evening.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165435/discussion-between-victor-and-fatihakici).

Comment: Hey ! Are you available yet

Comment: I created this for extension https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48880557/how-to-print-and-visualize-the-average-randomforestclassifier-of-all-trees-rathe