# Print the decision path of a specific sample in a random forest classifier

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

How to print the decision path of a randomforest rather than the path of individual trees in a randomforest for a specific sample.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000,
                           n_features=6,
                           n_informative=3,
                           n_classes=2,
                           random_state=0,
                           shuffle=False)

# Creating a dataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'Feature 1':X[:,0],
                                  'Feature 2':X[:,1],
                                  'Feature 3':X[:,2],
                                  'Feature 4':X[:,3],
                                  'Feature 5':X[:,4],
                                  'Feature 6':X[:,5],
                                  'Class':y})


y_train = df['Class']
X_train = df.drop('Class',axis = 1)

rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10,
                               random_state=0)

rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

decision_path for random forest was introduced in v0.18. (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html)

However, it outputs a sparse matrix which I'm not certain how to make sense of. Can anyone advise on how best to print the decision path of that specific sample and then visualize it?

```
#Extracting the decision path for instance i = 12
i_data = X_train.iloc[12].values.reshape(1,-1)
d_path = rf.decision_path(i_data)

print(d_path)
```

Output:

> (<1x1432 sparse matrix of type ''
>     with 96 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, array([   0,  133,  >282,  415,  588,  761,  910, 1041, 1182, 1309, 1432], dtype=int32))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found this [code](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_unveil_tree_structure.html) in the scikit-learn documentation and modified it to fit your problem.

As the [`RandomForestClassifier`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) is a collection of [`DecisionTreeClassifier`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier) we can iterate over the different trees and retrieve the decision path for the sample in each one.
Hope it helps:

```
import numpy as np

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000,
                           n_features=6,
                           n_informative=3,
                           n_classes=2,
                           random_state=0,
                           shuffle=False)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)

estimator = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10,
                               random_state=0)
estimator.fit(X_train, y_train)

# The decision estimator has an attribute called tree_  which stores the entire
# tree structure and allows access to low level attributes. The binary tree
# tree_ is represented as a number of parallel arrays. The i-th element of each
# array holds information about the node `i`. Node 0 is the tree's root. NOTE:
# Some of the arrays only apply to either leaves or split nodes, resp. In this
# case the values of nodes of the other type are arbitrary!
#
# Among those arrays, we have:
#   - left_child, id of the left child of the node
#   - right_child, id of the right child of the node
#   - feature, feature used for splitting the node
#   - threshold, threshold value at the node
#

# Using those arrays, we can parse the tree structure:

#n_nodes = estimator.tree_.node_count
n_nodes_ = [t.tree_.node_count for t in estimator.estimators_]
children_left_ = [t.tree_.children_left for t in estimator.estimators_]
children_right_ = [t.tree_.children_right for t in estimator.estimators_]
feature_ = [t.tree_.feature for t in estimator.estimators_]
threshold_ = [t.tree_.threshold for t in estimator.estimators_]


def explore_tree(estimator, n_nodes, children_left,children_right, feature,threshold,
                suffix='', print_tree= False, sample_id=0, feature_names=None):

    if not feature_names:
        feature_names = feature


    assert len(feature_names) == X.shape[1], "The feature names do not match the number of features."
    # The tree structure can be traversed to compute various properties such
    # as the depth of each node and whether or not it is a leaf.
    node_depth = np.zeros(shape=n_nodes, dtype=np.int64)
    is_leaves = np.zeros(shape=n_nodes, dtype=bool)

    stack = [(0, -1)]  # seed is the root node id and its parent depth
    while len(stack) > 0:
        node_id, parent_depth = stack.pop()
        node_depth[node_id] = parent_depth + 1

        # If we have a test node
        if (children_left[node_id] != children_right[node_id]):
            stack.append((children_left[node_id], parent_depth + 1))
            stack.append((children_right[node_id], parent_depth + 1))
        else:
            is_leaves[node_id] = True

    print("The binary tree structure has %s nodes"
          % n_nodes)
    if print_tree:
        print("Tree structure: \n")
        for i in range(n_nodes):
            if is_leaves[i]:
                print("%snode=%s leaf node." % (node_depth[i] * "\t", i))
            else:
                print("%snode=%s test node: go to node %s if X[:, %s] <= %s else to "
                      "node %s."
                      % (node_depth[i] * "\t",
                         i,
                         children_left[i],
                         feature[i],
                         threshold[i],
                         children_right[i],
                         ))
            print("\n")
        print()

    # First let's retrieve the decision path of each sample. The decision_path
    # method allows to retrieve the node indicator functions. A non zero element of
    # indicator matrix at the position (i, j) indicates that the sample i goes
    # through the node j.

    node_indicator = estimator.decision_path(X_test)

    # Similarly, we can also have the leaves ids reached by each sample.

    leave_id = estimator.apply(X_test)

    # Now, it's possible to get the tests that were used to predict a sample or
    # a group of samples. First, let's make it for the sample.

    #sample_id = 0
    node_index = node_indicator.indices[node_indicator.indptr[sample_id]:
                                        node_indicator.indptr[sample_id + 1]]

    print(X_test[sample_id,:])

    print('Rules used to predict sample %s: ' % sample_id)
    for node_id in node_index:
        # tabulation = " "*node_depth[node_id] #-> makes tabulation of each level of the tree
        tabulation = ""
        if leave_id[sample_id] == node_id:
            print("%s==> Predicted leaf index \n"%(tabulation))
            #continue

        if (X_test[sample_id, feature[node_id]] <= threshold[node_id]):
            threshold_sign = "<="
        else:
            threshold_sign = ">"

        print("%sdecision id node %s : (X_test[%s, '%s'] (= %s) %s %s)"
              % (tabulation,
                 node_id,
                 sample_id,
                 feature_names[feature[node_id]],
                 X_test[sample_id, feature[node_id]],
                 threshold_sign,
                 threshold[node_id]))
    print("%sPrediction for sample %d: %s"%(tabulation,
                                          sample_id,
                                          estimator.predict(X_test)[sample_id]))

    # For a group of samples, we have the following common node.
    sample_ids = [sample_id, 1]
    common_nodes = (node_indicator.toarray()[sample_ids].sum(axis=0) ==
                    len(sample_ids))

    common_node_id = np.arange(n_nodes)[common_nodes]

    print("\nThe following samples %s share the node %s in the tree"
          % (sample_ids, common_node_id))
    print("It is %s %% of all nodes." % (100 * len(common_node_id) / n_nodes,))

    for sample_id_ in sample_ids:
        print("Prediction for sample %d: %s"%(sample_id_,
                                          estimator.predict(X_test)[sample_id_]))
```

And for printing the different trees in the random forest you can just iterate over the estimators this way:

```
for i,e in enumerate(estimator.estimators_):

    print("Tree %d\n"%i)
    explore_tree(estimator.estimators_[i],n_nodes_[i],children_left_[i],
                 children_right_[i], feature_[i],threshold_[i],
                suffix=i, sample_id=1, feature_names=["Feature_%d"%i for i in range(X.shape[1])])
    print('\n'*2)
```

This is the output for the first trees in the `RandomForestClassifier` for `sample_id = 0`:

```
Tree 1

The binary tree structure has 115 nodes
[ 2.36609963  1.32658511 -0.08002818  0.88295736  2.24224824 -0.71469736]
Rules used to predict sample 1: 
decision id node 0 : (X_test[1, 'Feature_3'] (= 0.8829573603562209) > 0.7038955688476562)
decision id node 86 : (X_test[1, 'Feature_2'] (= -0.08002817952064323) > -1.4465678930282593)
decision id node 92 : (X_test[1, 'Feature_0'] (= 2.366099632530947) > 0.7020512223243713)
decision id node 102 : (X_test[1, 'Feature_5'] (= -0.7146973587899221) > -1.2842652797698975)
decision id node 106 : (X_test[1, 'Feature_2'] (= -0.08002817952064323) > -0.4031955599784851)
decision id node 110 : (X_test[1, 'Feature_0'] (= 2.366099632530947) > 0.717217206954956)
decision id node 112 : (X_test[1, 'Feature_4'] (= 2.2422482391211678) <= 3.0181679725646973)
==> Predicted leaf index
decision id node 113 : (X_test[1, 'Feature_4'] (= 2.2422482391211678) > -2.0)
Prediction for sample 1: 1.0

The following samples [1, 1] share the node [  0  86  92 102 106 110 112 113] in the tree
It is 6.956521739130435 % of all nodes.
Prediction for sample 1: 1.0
Prediction for sample 1: 1.0



Tree 2

The binary tree structure has 135 nodes
[ 2.36609963  1.32658511 -0.08002818  0.88295736  2.24224824 -0.71469736]
Rules used to predict sample 1: 
decision id node 0 : (X_test[1, 'Feature_3'] (= 0.8829573603562209) > 0.5484486818313599)
decision id node 88 : (X_test[1, 'Feature_2'] (= -0.08002817952064323) > -0.7239605188369751)
decision id node 102 : (X_test[1, 'Feature_5'] (= -0.7146973587899221) > -1.6143207550048828)
decision id node 110 : (X_test[1, 'Feature_0'] (= 2.366099632530947) > 2.3399271965026855)
decision id node 130 : (X_test[1, 'Feature_5'] (= -0.7146973587899221) <= -0.5680553913116455)
decision id node 131 : (X_test[1, 'Feature_0'] (= 2.366099632530947) <= 2.4545814990997314)
==> Predicted leaf index
decision id node 132 : (X_test[1, 'Feature_4'] (= 2.2422482391211678) > -2.0)
Prediction for sample 1: 0.0

The following samples [1, 1] share the node [  0  88 102 110 130 131 132] in the tree
It is 5.185185185185185 % of all nodes.
Prediction for sample 1: 0.0
Prediction for sample 1: 0.0
```

Comment: this is amazing ! thank you. Can we print the feature names/ Column titles instead of just the value ?

Comment: Yes, just define an input list of names to the function. Take a look now.